# My Visual Studio Code Intellisense is simply not working (Ionic/Angular Project)

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Basically The Problem is that i can't get any suggestions. For example i need the angular-features suggestions, the ionic-feature suggestions, TypeScript attribute suggestions and so on. I get suggestions but completely useless ones and ones completely out of context.

So far i tried reinstalling VS Code several times. I also tried changing the suggestion settings but nothing works for me.

Anyone had a similar problem? I really need to fix this it is driving me absolutely nuts.

Comment: Use IntelliJ.  ;-)

Comment: could u provide more than IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Intelij is the best and make sure you have the plugin for that language or framework installed and that plugin is enabled for your project. That goes for VS Code and Intelij

Comment: Does the free Version of IntelliJ also support ionic, Typescript and so on?

Comment: it supports everything on development